# PHP files without extensions

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is it bad to use:

```
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
```

and to save files without a file extention (e.g. `index` instead of `index.php`)? The intention is to hide/remove `.php` from the URL and to stop users from manually putting e.g. `/example.php`.

Comment: use `.htaccess` to hide the extension.

Comment: Yes, I have WAMP installed on Windows and it works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the file extension, add this to the .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

change `.php` to the proper file extension

new link :

```
<a href="file">link text</a>
```

#### Edit :

Save your files as `index.php`, `about.php`, and so on

Comment: Does this work for files in sub-directories? e.g. `/folder/script` => `/folder/script.php`?

Comment: If you place this in the .htaccess file of your root, it will apply to all enclosing subfolders. This means the .htaccess file in root will affect /sub/file.php (now /sub/file), but /sub/.htaccess will not affect /file.php

Comment: `.htaccess` carry onto subfolders. Perhaps your files are a different extension? If all your files are the same extension (ie `.php`), try copying your `.htaccess` file to the subfolder and see if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Yes it is bad.

The right way to do that is by using `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` files.

Answer (score 0):

Its not good practice to change extension as it will need configuration for web server each time and so its a portability issue.

You should use .htaccess directives to setup any level of customization.
And in best practice you can route all requests to index.php to avoid direct access of php files.